# Visual Studio not seeing all my files after git pull

Tags: c#, git, github, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a C# project from 2 computers. I made changes from one of the computers and committed the changes and then pushed them to gitHub. On my other PC I pulled the changes using `git pull` command.
Now I can see the new files added to the project in windows explorer. but visual studio doesn't see them for some reason.
I even deleted the whole project on the second computer and cloned the project again but that didn't help.
What am I missing? is this related to VS project settings?

Comment: Did you commit the changes to the project to git?

Comment: Actually the git knows that its new files but VS doesnt know, you need to do Under `Project` `->` `Show All files` after that you should see files that are not included in the project then just right click and choose `Include in project`

Answer (score 0):

Likely your changed project file was not saved or not committed. Check the commit has changes to the .csproj file. If not, save the changed project file, and make a new commit.

I have been bitten by this a few times, and now mash ctrl-shift-s (save all) in VS before committing.

Answer (score 0):

Such of hundreds of problems:

- Close solution and reopen it!
  It

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).